# Moved Development to new machine, now it won't compile

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017

My laptop died so I restored my code to my desktop.  I use Xamarin for VS 2017.  When I compile I get a "java exited with code 1" error, the logs contain the following:

```
Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage|Information|0|Hooked up SDB tracing adapter
Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage|Information|0|Initialization finished
Xamarin|Information|0|Xamarin - 4.12.3.83-d15-9+23fa80172
Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage|Information|0|Hooked up SDB tracing adapter
Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage|Information|0|Initialization finished
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.XamarinAndroidPackage|Warning|0|Initializing Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.XamarinAndroidPackage
Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable|Warning|0|An error occurred getting the Project Node for 'C:\Users\HP_administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\OML Android\OML Android\OML Android.csproj'
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'EnvDTE.SolutionClass' to interface type 'EnvDTE.Project'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{866311E6-C887-4143-9833-645F5B93F6F1}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VsShellExtensions.ToDteProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy) in E:\A\_work\1824\s\src\Core\Xamarin.VisualStudio.Interfaces\Extensions\VsShellExtensions.cs:line 233
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable.OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(UInt32 docCookie, Int32 fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame) in E:\A\_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio\DocumentObservable.cs:line 33
Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable|Warning|0|An error occurred getting the Project Node for 'C:\Users\HP_administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\OML Android\OML Android\OML Android.csproj'
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'EnvDTE.SolutionClass' to interface type 'EnvDTE.Project'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{866311E6-C887-4143-9833-645F5B93F6F1}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VsShellExtensions.ToDteProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy) in E:\A\_work\1824\s\src\Core\Xamarin.VisualStudio.Interfaces\Extensions\VsShellExtensions.cs:line 233
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable.OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(UInt32 docCookie, Int32 fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame) in E:\A\_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio\DocumentObservable.cs:line 33
Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable|Warning|0|An error occurred getting the Project Node for 'C:\Users\HP_administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\OML Android\OML Android\OML Android.csproj'
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'EnvDTE.SolutionClass' to interface type 'EnvDTE.Project'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{866311E6-C887-4143-9833-645F5B93F6F1}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VsShellExtensions.ToDteProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy) in E:\A\_work\1824\s\src\Core\Xamarin.VisualStudio.Interfaces\Extensions\VsShellExtensions.cs:line 233
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable.OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(UInt32 docCookie, Int32 fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame) in E:\A\_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio\DocumentObservable.cs:line 33
Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable|Warning|0|An error occurred getting the Project Node for 'C:\Users\HP_administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\OML Android\OML Android\OML Android.csproj'
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'EnvDTE.SolutionClass' to interface type 'EnvDTE.Project'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{866311E6-C887-4143-9833-645F5B93F6F1}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VsShellExtensions.ToDteProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy) in E:\A\_work\1824\s\src\Core\Xamarin.VisualStudio.Interfaces\Extensions\VsShellExtensions.cs:line 233
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable.OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(UInt32 docCookie, Int32 fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame) in E:\A\_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio\DocumentObservable.cs:line 33
Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable|Warning|0|An error occurred getting the Project Node for 'C:\Users\HP_administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\OML Android\OML Android\OML Android.csproj'
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'EnvDTE.SolutionClass' to interface type 'EnvDTE.Project'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{866311E6-C887-4143-9833-645F5B93F6F1}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VsShellExtensions.ToDteProject(IVsHierarchy hierarchy) in E:\A\_work\1824\s\src\Core\Xamarin.VisualStudio.Interfaces\Extensions\VsShellExtensions.cs:line 233
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.DocumentObservable.OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(UInt32 docCookie, Int32 fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame) in E:\A\_work\1824\s\src\Core\VisualStudio\DocumentObservable.cs:line 33
```

This is not the entire log (won't fit here), but you should get the idea.

I have no idea what these errors mean, am I missing some package registrations or some such?

Comment: I believe this might be specific to VS 2017. It is highly recommended to upgrade to VS 2019!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the installation folder on Windows 10 is different than Windows 7.  I restored my backup-up to \User\\source\repos and everything compiled and deployed successfully.